# How does GHCi pick names for type variables?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, ghc, ghci, type-variables

When using the interactive GHC interpreter, it's possible to ask for the inferred type of an expression:

```
Prelude> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

It seems that it takes the names of the type variables from the signature since `map` is [defined](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-Base.html#map) as

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

in the Prelude. That makes a lot of sense! My question is: how are type variable names picked when there is no signature given?

An example would be

```
Prelude> :t map fst
map fst :: [(b, b1)] -> [b]
```

where it picked names `b` and `b1`. It's clear that renaming must take place, but simply starting with `a`, `b`, ... would have given

```
map fst :: [(a, b)] -> [a]
```

instead, which I find slightly more readable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I understand it, `ghci` chooses names in the same order that it infers the types. It uses the naming scheme as you mentioned to decide the type name of the result, which is `[b]` because that is the type name specified in the definition of `map`. It then decides that the function that is the first parameter to `map` should return something of type `b` also.

The remaining type variable to be named is thus the type variable for the second element in the argument tuple to `fst`, and again, it looks at the definition of `fst` to decide which name to use. The definition of `fst :: (a, b) -> a`, so `b` would be the preferred name here, but since `b` is already taken, it appends a `1` so that it becomes `b1`.

I think that this system has advantages in situations where you don't deal with arbitrary types as is the case here. If the resulting type looks something like this, for example:

```
castAdd :: (Num n, Num n1, Num n2) => n -> n1 -> n2
```

... it is arguably more readable than:

```
castAdd :: (Num a, Num b, Num c) => a -> b -> c
```

... because you can mostly rely on that `n#` signifies a numeric type, since the class definition for `Num` is `class Num n where ...`.

EDIT: Yes, I know that `castAdd` is impossible to implement, but it's just a type example.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice explanation! I had not thought of the case where you want several `n`'s to be renamed but stay related.

Comment: Its not impossible. (unSafeCoerce or just plain old `_|_`)