# How does ghci choose names for type variables?

Tags: list, haskell, types, ghc, type-inference

I made this function:

```
compose []     = id
compose (x:xs) = x  . (compose xs)
```

And when I asked for the type:

```
:t compose
compose :: [b -> b] -> b -> b
```

Why does it give `compose :: [b -> b] -> b -> b` and not `compose :: [a -> a] -> a -> a` if a comes first in alphabetic order?

Saying that, I will add this other example:

```
badImplementationOfCompose []     = id
badImplementationOfCompose (x:xs) =  (badImplementationOfCompose xs)

:t badImplementationOfCompose
badImplementationOfCompose :: [a1] -> a2 -> a2
```

It might give some hints...

Comment: GHCi tries to use the names of the type variables occurring in the types of the functions you use. Which name survives is hard to guess since the inference algorithm is rather complex. Here, it seems that `b` comes from the type of `.`, or at least that's my guess. The order unification is performed apparently chooses that instead of the other names.

Comment: From the two targets, [the older one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8519964/2751851) explains the gist of it in a tidy way, while [the newer one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24536673/2751851) discusses some of the edge cases.

Comment: @duplode thanks as always helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess it has to do with the type of `.` which is

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

and it just starts replacing from there when inferring the type.

`a` has to be equal to `b` and `b` has to be equal to `c`. So in short my guess is that it tries to keep type variable naming in line with the type variable names in used sub-functions if possible.

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

GHCi starts with a generic type if none function is given, I'm talking about my second example:

```
badImplementationOfCompose []     = id
badImplementationOfCompose (x:xs) =  (badImplementationOfCompose xs)
```

it has the type of `id` beeing `a -> a` so if another type variable is needed, it start adding by one

```
badImplementationOfCompose :: [a1] -> a2 -> a2
```

And I thougth, maybe @chi was absolutelly right, and the names comes from the functions, so I made a case with my own `id`:

```
id2 :: c -> c
id2 x = x

badImplementationOfCompose []     = id2
badImplementationOfCompose (x:xs) =  (badImplementationOfCompose xs)
```

and the type was as expected:

```
:t badImplementationOfCompose
badImplementationOfCompose :: [a] -> c -> c
```

The first type variable was `a` created by GHCi, and `c -> c` was taken from `id2`